# ARMv8 (AArch64, ARM64) opcodes list

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm sorry for such as questions where answer would seem to be easily searched in google...

Some time ago I have seen table/list of ARMv8 instructions with opcodes and it was perfect, but I lost link. Now I'm trying to find at least some sources where opcodes of instructions listed and can't.

There're some C headers, where opcodes defined in non-readable form, lot of different scientific publications with 1k+ pages (containing no opcodes), etc., but I can't find simple list.

Could somebody point me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doc may be interesting for you:
https://github.com/CAS-Atlantic/AArch64-Encoding

Comment: It's definitely better source that I provided. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 7):

**Eureka!**

---

[**HERE IS THIS TABLE**](http://kitoslab-eng.blogspot.com/2012/10/armv8-aarch64-instruction-encoding.html)

---

**P.S.** It's really hard to google it (keywords I used - "b arm64 opcode"), so I decided to post it as answer. Hope it'll be helpful for others.

Answer (score 5):

The canonical source is the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile). 
If you prefer machine readable format, the  [XML files are available too](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/a-profile/exploration-tools).

Comment: Yes, I've tried to work with official docs, but it takes too much time to extract needed information (at least for me), that's why I searched for something well structured with minimal amount of information doesn't related to subject. But anyway thank you for sharing links to official documents, it definitely will be useful for future researchers.

Comment: @OlvinRoght For my case the accepted answer does not provide any useful info about the opcodes. The above ARM manual does it well. Here is a direct link https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0596/a/DDI_0596_ARM_a64_instruction_set_architecture.pdf.

Comment: @Biswapriyo It means that our cases are completely different. I've needed opcodes for patching obfuscated application and even table I provided in my answer was enough.